# Where can i find the options for Selenium module?

Tags: python, selenium

Where can i find all the configurable options for Selenium module in Python?
For example, the code below are some of the configurable options for the webdriver, but there seems to be no documentation on the full list of options.
Does anyone have a good documentation on the options? Much appreciated!

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
chrome_options.add_argument('headless')
```

Couldnt find the documentation online

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the Chrome command line switches here:

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/